# Why do I see so few homeless people / beggars in cities in the Netherlands?

Tags: netherlands, beggars

This summer I went on a trip to the Netherlands visiting cities of various sizes throughout the country from south east to north west. The main stops (for which my question is meant) were Eindhoven, s-Hertogenbosch, Dordrecht, Rotterdam, Den Haag, Leiden.

At some point during this trip I noticed that the only beggar (i.e. homeless person in shabby clothes asking for money, no offense!) I ever saw was a woman in Eindhoven. Coming from Germany I am used to being asked for some money in pretty much every city.

I looked up the ratio of homeless people of both countries [on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_homeless_population) and it states 0.42% for Germany and 0.19% for the Netherlands. So as a matter of fact, there are homeless people in the Netherlands, but why did I not see them in any of the cities listed above?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about Dutch society; not travel.

Comment: At which stackexchange community would this question be better placed? I'd be happy to have this migrated or to ask this again somewhere else.

Comment: I don't know, but in any case just because it's off-topic everywhere else doesn't make it on-topic here.

Comment: @fkraiem Wow.. I did not even suggest it is on topic here because it might be off-topic everywhere else. You might calm down. I accepted your point and was asking if anyone (the question was not even for you only) can suggest where this question might be better placed.

Comment: I think @fkraiem's response was because you asked "at which stackexchange community" rather than "is there any SE community" -- which could suggest you thought every possible question _must_ be on topic _somewhere_ on SE.

Comment: It might be on topic in Politics SE, under the assumption that the Netherlands have policies with the intentional or secondary effect to reduce public begging.

Comment: It might be that they try to keep the areas high with tourist activity 'clean' of beggars and the like. They (try) to do that in Belgium too. So they are still there, just in the less traversed area's where tourists might go.

Comment: There is also a movement that helps people to keep clean, get regular 'new' second hand clothing, having them get a bit of income out of selling a newspaper. There are also shelters for those who want to stay overnight (if never as many places as are needed) and the police does not allow people to sleep/set up home in the middle of the street, which happens often in other countries.